# Chern Classes or Chern character classes in the Lichtenbaum-Quillen conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, chern-classes

Let $F$ be a number field, $\mathcal{O}$ its ring of integers, $r>1$ an integer and $\ell$ a prime number different from $2$.
The Lichtenbaum-Quillen conjecture, now a theorem by Voevodsky, Rost, et al., asserts that for $k= 1,2$ there is a natural isomorphism

$$
\operatorname{K}_{2r-k}(\mathcal{O}) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_{\ell} \cong \operatorname{H}^k \left( \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O} [\frac{1}{\ell}]; \mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(r)\right)
$$
from the algebraic K-theory of $\mathcal{O}$ to the continuous étale cohomology.
(See e.g. Theorem 5.6.8 in [Kolster's article](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3497675)).
I want to know:

> Is this isomorphism induced by the Chern class $\mathit{c}_{r,k}$? Or by the Chern character class $\mathit{ch}_{r,k}$?

One of the reasons I am puzzled is that there seems to be some disagreement in the literature which is partially due to the fact that rationally this plays not as much of a role. But of course integrally it does.
For example Theorem 61 in [Weibel's article](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2181823) suggests that the Chern class should be used in the local case on the other hand [Kahn's article](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1367295) predicts the Chern character class to be the right candidate.

EDIT: I decided in favour of the Chern character class following Theorem 5 due to Friedlander in [Soulé's article](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=689380). Although not explicitly stated, it shows surjectivity of the Chern character. In the proof Adams work on the integrality of the Chern character for the topological K-theory of a point is explicitly used which is maybe the most convincing argument. I have to confess that I still don't understand how Kahn proves that his "Anti-Chern class" is right inverse to the Chern character.